# displaying the results of a query on an invoices table month by month, year by year

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an invoices table in my database, one of the fields of which is a created date.

Users can enter a date range and the query will get results from between the range given. I want to then go through the results and display them so that all the results from, for example, jan 2013 are in a table together (pref with totals for that table), feb 2013 invoices are all in a table together and so on across years if requested.

I've never had to do something like this before and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Has anyone had to deal with this before and if so what was the best method to do so?

Comment: Can you post the code you have now?

Comment: Please show us your table structure and the outcome you would like to have. It is kind of confusing right now.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer since you might not know the first part...do the hard part directly in you SQL instead of some massive php loop. Select whatever you want to display and end the query with:

```
WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' GROUP BY YEAR(invoice_date), MONTH(invoice_date)
```

You can pass the 2 php variables through php from the form your users use to enter the date range. Make sure you quote them if you're using DATETIME format and getting it through datepicker for example. Then it should be a piece of cake to go from there with php and display it the way you want...

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing in my rails project.

1st you fetch records 'group by invoice_year invoice_month'

then i built a hash(or any data structure you prefer) and add data corresponding to that year and month. Then use this to build your table

example: range is jan-2013 to present day

invoice_data = {'2013' =>  { 'jan' => {some data}, 'feb' => {some data}...}, '2014' => {'jan' {some data}}}

you have to format the query data and build such data structure.

look at extract method in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `SQL GROUP BY` Statement ( http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp ).

Assuming you have the totals of the invoices in a field called invoice_total and that your invoice date is in a field called invoice_date the following SQL statement could be used:

```
SELECT sum(invoice_total), year, month 
FROM invoices
GROUP BY YEAR(invoice_date) as year, MONTH(invoice_date) as month
```